# Concatenating file names with a delimiter using UNIX

Tags: shell, unix

I have a list of files based on a pattern in a directory which i would like to concatenate with some delimiter in between.

Eg: Multiple files in the directory like

```
File1.csv

File2.csv

File3.csv
```

Output: `File1.csv,File2.csv,File3.csv`

Note - I just want to concatenate the name of the files and return that as an output and not the data.

How can we do this in UNIX? Any help will be appreciated.

i have tried the "paste" command - but that concatenates the data as well.

Comment: could you share what you tried so far?

Comment: you can do `ls -1 File* | tr "\n" ","`

Comment: @dr-claw the OP probably wants: `ls -1 *.csv | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//'` (CSV files; remove trailing comma).. but the question needs more info/current attempts to get a better idea

Comment: @costaparas Correct, would not want any trailing comma

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple shell pipeline as follows:

```
ls -1 *.csv | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//'
```

- [`ls -1`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) gets you the filenames on separate lines
- [`tr`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tr.1.html) maps the newlines to commas
- [`sed`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html) removes the trailing comma

Answer (score 1):

From `ls` man page:

`-m     fill width with a comma separated list of entries`

So you can do:

```sh
ls -m *.csv | tr -d ' '
```

`tr -d ' '`  (you can also use `tr -d '[:space:]'`) is for deleting the space between comma and next file, without output will look like
`File1.csv, File2.csv`

or

```sh
ls -m *.csv | sed 's/, /,/g'
```

The second one is better since if you have spaces in your file name it will not delete them.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.csv" -type f -printf "%f," |
awk '{ print substr($0,1,(length($0)-1))}'
```

Use find's printf to add commas to the end of each file and then pipe through to awk to remove the last trailing comma.

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` with a Perl one-liner:

```
find . -printf "%f\n" | perl -lne 'push @f, $_; END { print join q{,}, @f; }'
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.

Answer (score 0):

Print the files and use `paste`.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.csv" -type f | paste -sd,
```